# Keras multi target classification model test accuracy is less than train accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am building multi classification model, after fit method, getting test accuracy is very very less than train accuracy even drop outs layers attached.

The layers definition is as follows.

```
n_labels = len(unique(X_train_enc))
in_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
em_layer = Embedding(input_dim = int(n_labels)+1,output_dim = 7,
                     input_length = 1, name="embedding")(in_layer)

dense = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(em_layer)
dense = Dropout(0.2)(dense)
output = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(dense)
model = Model(inputs=in_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train_enc, epochs=100, batch_size=100, verbose=1)
```

Epoch 98/100
572/572 [==============================] - 11s 19ms/step - loss: 3.7565e-11 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 99/100
313/572 [===============>..............] - ETA: 5s - loss: 2.2852e-11 - accuracy: 1.0000

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test_enc, y_test_enc,verbose=1)
print('Test Accuracy: ', test_acc, '\nTest Loss: ', test_loss)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (test_acc*100))
```

766/766 [==============================] - 7s 9ms/step - loss: 20.4420 - accuracy: 0.1426
Test Accuracy:  0.1426003873348236
Test Loss:  20.441951751708984
Accuracy: 14.26

any tuning will be highly appreciated.

Comment: While training, it helps to provide the model some validation data. Do this by `model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train_enc, validation_data=(X_test_enc, y_test_enc), epochs=100, batch_size=100, verbose=1)`

Comment: You should replace `X_test_enc` and `y_test_enc` with their respective validation data pairs, which you can obtain during `train_test_split`

Comment: ok, thanks , let me try that and come back to you.

Comment: No luck,                                                                            
 model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train_enc, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid_enc,y_valid_enc),batch_size=100, verbose=1)                                         Epoch 99/100
653/653 [==============================] - 14s 22ms/step - loss: 2.6296e-10 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 23.6754 - val_accuracy: 0.1488
Epoch 100/100
653/653 [==============================] - 13s 21ms/step - loss: 2.4104e-10 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 23.6777 - val_accuracy: 0.1488

Comment: 256/256 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 24.2790 - accuracy: 0.1366
Test Accuracy:  0.13662540912628174 
Test Loss:  24.27897071838379
Accuracy: 13.66

Comment: I got it. Train accuracy being more than the test accuracy is because the model is overfitting on the train data, and the train and test data are not true representations of each other. Either that, or you would need to make your model a bit more 'Deeper' by adding more Dense layers and so on.